# How to make unigram, bigram, trigram model from sentences or data train on file.txt in Python?

Tags: python-3.7

i have some code to make unigram, bigram, and trigram from some sentences, but i want this code can make it from file.txt , im newbie in programing let me know what i must do ?

```
def ngrams(s, n=2, i=0):
while len(s[i:i+n]) == n:
    yield s[i:i+n]
    i += 1

txt ='Python is one of the awesomest languages'

unigram = ngrams(txt.split(), n=1)
a = list(unigram)

bigram = ngrams(txt.split(), n=2)
b = list(bigram)

trigram = ngrams(txt.split(), n=3)
c = list(trigram)

print('unigram:')
print(a)
print('bigram:')
print(b)
print('trigram:')
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to write a file (notice the 'w' in the open statement):

```py
with (open('some.txt', 'w')) as file:
    file.write("this is an example!")
```

When you want to read a file (notice the 'r' in the open statement):

```py
with (open('some.txt', 'r')) as file:
    line = file.readline();
    print(line)
```

This should be a good starting point for you.